# How to sum two columns using sub query in a grouped data of joined tables

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I've a query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Avalied
FROM PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB as lm
JOIN PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB as ls 
ON lm.LV_TransMasterId = ls.LV_TransMasterId
WHERE lm.SystemCode = 'faheem123' AND lm.EmployeeCode = '0014' AND lm.Status ='Approved'
Group by lm.Status
```

The Above query returns:

```
Availed
-------
   3
```

and another query :

```
SELECT PY_Leave + CY_Leave as Openning 
FROM PY_LeaveOpeningTAB 
WHERE SystemCode = 'faheem123' and EmployeeCode = '0014'
```

this query returns :

```
Openning
--------
   25
   23
   30
```

I want to combine the above two queries to get the below result :

```
Openning   Availed
--------   --------
   25         3
   23         0
   30         0
```

How do I achieve the above result? Thanks :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you want "3" for `Availed` on all three rows?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me that you would want "3" on one row but "0" on the other rows.  You could do something like this:

```
SELECT (PY_Leave + CY_Leave) as Openning,
       (CASE WHEN PY_Leave + CY_Leave = 25 THEN x.Avalied ELSE 0 END) as Avalied
FROM PY_LeaveOpeningTAB lo CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as Avalied
      FROM PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB lm JOIN
           PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB as ls 
           ON lm.LV_TransMasterId = ls.LV_TransMasterId
      WHERE lm.SystemCode = 'faheem123' AND lm.EmployeeCode = '0014' AND
            lm.Status ='Approved'
     ) x
WHERE lo.SystemCode = 'faheem123' and lo.EmployeeCode = '0014';
```

As I say, it makes more sense (to me) to remove the `CASE` and put the "3" on all three "matching" rows.

Comment: for `Openning` of value `25` there are 3 row counts in `PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB` table and for others there is no row count found in `PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB` table, that's why I want to display `0` for them, your query will always return `0` for availed if `Openning` is `25`, I want to display the corresponding row count if found and if not then display `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a using a CTE

```
 WITH CTE_preselect AS (
 SELECT EmployeeCode,PY_Leave + CY_Leave as Openning 
 FROM PY_LeaveOpeningTAB 
 WHERE SystemCode = 'faheem123' and EmployeeCode = '0014'
 )

 SELECT Openning,COUNT(*) as Avalied
 FROM PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB as lm
 JOIN PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB as ls 
 ON lm.LV_TransMasterId = ls.LV_TransMasterId
 JOIN CTE_preselect ON lm.EmployeeCode = CTE_preselect.EmployeeCode
 WHERE lm.SystemCode = 'faheem123' AND lm.EmployeeCode = '0014' AND 
 lm.Status ='Approved'
 Group by Openning,lm.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Availed "belongs" to the first row

```
Select A.Opening
      ,Availed = case when A.RN=1 then B.Availed else 0 end)
 From (
        SELECT PY_Leave + CY_Leave as Openning 
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Order by (Select NULL))
         FROM PY_LeaveOpeningTAB 
         WHERE SystemCode = 'faheem123' and EmployeeCode = '0014'
      ) A
 Cross Join (
                SELECT COUNT(*) as Avalied
                FROM PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB as lm
                JOIN PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB as ls 
                ON lm.LV_TransMasterId = ls.LV_TransMasterId
                WHERE lm.SystemCode = 'faheem123' AND lm.EmployeeCode = '0014' AND lm.Status ='Approved'
                Group by lm.Status
            ) B
```